# Malloc syntax in C

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list, malloc

In the books I read that the syntax for malloc is malloc(sizeof(int)) but in one of doubly linked list program I see the following:

```
newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node))
```

What is (struct node*) doing here? What is this entire code doing?  btw, the code for the struct in the program is as below.

```
struct node
{
char line[80];
struct node *next,*prev;
};

struct node *start=NULL,*temp,*temp1,*temp2,*newnode;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is dynamically creating a `pointer` to a single type of `struct node`. In most versions of C, the `(struct node *)` cast is not needed, and some argue that it shouldn't be used. If you remove the cast, it will be a `void*`, which can be used for any type.

Therefore:

```
newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

See: [Specifically, what's dangerous about casting the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc)

*Note 1: If you are using Visual Studio to write your C code, it will give you red underlining if you don't cast the result of `malloc`. However, the code will still compile.*

*Note 2: Using `malloc` in C++ code requires you to cast the result as shown in your example.*

Comment: The consensus on here seems not to do it, but I think it's important to mention that a _lot_ of books recommend it - including 'The C Programming Language' itself.

Comment: @teppic Correct. There has even been much debate about the topic here on several StackOverflow questions. Personally, I think the hate for casting the return of malloc is a bit overblown.

Comment: Thank you @Inisheer..  that was exactly what I wanted to know!!  :)

Comment: @Inisheer It's not overblown. If you didn't include the correct header, you'd be casting what the compiler assumes a function that returns `int` to `struct node*`. Effectively hiding the error. There should be no cast on that line. Secondly, the question is tagged with `C`, what C++ does has no bearing here. Thirdly, a bug in a compiler (or an IDE) is no reason to use bad code.

Comment: @Wiz You are correct. But I think the overall level of distaste for casting is a bit much. But that's my opinion. Secondly, although the question was tagged C, I assumed from the content of the question that the OP was a novice C programmer and could benefit from the notes about C++ in the event he/she uses Visual Studio or sees malloc being cast within C++ code in the future. Effectively, I'm trying to directly answer the question, but also provide possible guidance in the future.

Comment: Bottom line: there are much MUCH worse "errors" you can make in C and C++ than casting the return of malloc.

Answer (score 3):

You ran into a very bad code. C programmers never cast a result of `malloc()`. Not only it is not needed but [can be harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: This is highly discussable, as you can run into similar problems the other way round, look here: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEM02-C.+Immediately+cast+the+result+of+a+memory+allocation+function+call+into+a+pointer+to+the+allocated+type

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the number of bytes that you want `malloc` to allocate as argument. That is why in this code sample you use `sizeof(struct node)` telling `C` to allocate the number of bytes needed for a struct node variable. Casting the result like is shown in this code is bad idea by the way.

Answer (score 2):

malloc returns a void pointer .

(struct node*) does a explicit conversion from void pointer to the target pointer type

Answer (score 1):

"malloc" returns a void-pointer. (struct node *) is type-casting the result of malloc to a "node struct pointer", which is (undoubtibly) what "newnode" is.